# How do I allow the state of an LED to be changed from multiple inputs at once? (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, flask, cron, raspberry-pi, led

I am a complete beginner to Raspberry Pi and Python programming so I am still getting to grips with the basics.

I am making a project which allows an LED to be switched on/off using three possible methods:

- Using a tactile button wired to the Pi
- A virtual button which is displayed on a HTML page hosted by a Flask server
- The LED is switched on/off when the sun sets/rises using Cron and a program called sunwait (https://github.com/risacher/sunwait)

I have these three methods working independently, but I want to allow them to work together. For example, to display the HTML page which can switch the LED on/off I am running a Flask server from a Python script. But to allow for the button to switch the LED on/off, I have a separate script. Is it possible to combine these two scripts? Or should I find a way to have them both running simultaneously?

My light.py file:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(18)

def light_on():
    led.on()
    print ("Light has been switched on")

def light_off():
    led.off()
    print ("Light has been switched off")

def light_switch():
    led.toggle()
```

My app.py file which runs the Flask server (hosts the index.html file that contains the virtual on/off button):

```
import light
from flask import Flask, render_template
from gpiozero import Button, LED
from time import sleep

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/led_on', methods=['POST'])
def led_on():
    light.light_on()
    print("Light has been switched on")

@app.route('/led_off', methods=['POST'])
def led_off():
    light.light_off()
    print("Light has been switched off")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

My button.py file:

```
import light
from gpiozero import Button
from time import sleep

button = Button(22)

while True:
    button.wait_for_press()
    light.light_switch()
    sleep(0.5)
```

My cron entries as follows:

```
*/5 * * * * sunwait sun up 51.886661N 8.618732W ; python /home/pi/development/smart-lighting-app/light_off.py
*/5 * * * * sunwait sun down 51.886661N 8.618732W ; python /home/pi/development/smart-lighting-app/light_on.py
```

And I have the following basic scripts which are called from the cron entries:

light_on.py:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(18)

while True:
    led.on()
    print ("The light is switched ON")
    sleep(300.0)
```

light_off.py:

```
from gpiozero import LED
from time import sleep

led = LED(18)

while True:
    led.off()
    print ("The light is switched OFF")
    sleep(300.0)
```

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. As I say, I am a beginner to this and I am generally looking for the best way to structure this project. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an inherent race condition. What if your sunrise switcher is just switching the LED on as the user presses `toggle` or `on` or `off`? The result will depend which one happens first.